# LuaLaTeX + luatexja-fontspec: 利用されるフォントを、直接プロジェクトフォルダから利用出来ますか？

Tags: latex

下記の様に指定しても、パソコンに`MS Mincho`と`MS Gothic`が無ければ、正しいフォントが表示してくれません。

```
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont[BoldFont=HGMinchoB]{MS Mincho}
\setsansjfont[BoldFont=KozGoPro-Bold]{MS Gothic}
```

`LuaLaTeX`として出来るかどうか、未だ存じておりませんが、合理上利用されるフォントを直接フロンエンドのフォルダーの中に保管すれば完璧解決のではないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記は、正しい構文ではないですが、下記のようにフォントが利用できますでしょうか。

```
\setmainjfont[BoldFont=HGMinchoB]{'./../fonts/msgothic.ttc' , './../fonts/HGRMB.TTC'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange に[類似の質問](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357489/)がありました．

luatexja-fontspec の場合も同様の方法が使えるようです．手許に MS Gothic 等のフォントがないので，[にしき的フォント](http://hwm3.gyao.ne.jp/shiroi-niwatori/nishiki-teki.htm)の例になりますが，以下のようなディレクトリ構成で

```
.
├── nishiki-teki
│   └── nishiki-teki.ttf
└── test.tex
```

次の LaTeX 文書を lualatex に **`-recorder` オプションを付けて**処理すると，相対パスで指定したフォントファイルのフォントが出力 PDF に埋め込まれます．

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\setmainjfont[
  Path          = \currfileabsdir,
  UprightFont   = nishiki-teki/nishiki-teki.ttf,
  BoldFont      = nishiki-teki/nishiki-teki.ttf,
]{nishiki-teki}

\setsansjfont[
  Path          = \currfileabsdir,
  UprightFont   = nishiki-teki/nishiki-teki.ttf,
  BoldFont      = nishiki-teki/nishiki-teki.ttf,
]{nishiki-teki}

\begin{document}

mainのフォント．{\bfseries boldのフォント．}{\sffamily\gtfamily sansのフォント．}

\end{document}
```

[image: にしき的フォントが埋め込まれた結果]

また，LuaTeX の場合は `\directlua` が使えて，なおかつ Lua の lfs ライブラリを用いるとカレントディレクトリが簡単に取得できるので，上の `\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}` の代わりに

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

でも ok ですね．この場合は `-recorder` オプションも不要です．

Comment: ご回答、誠にありがとうございます！