# Windows環境で\directluaを使って正しい絶対パスを取得する方法

Tags: latex, lua

質問 [LuaLaTeX + luatexja-fontspec: 利用されるフォントを、直接プロジェクトフォルダから利用出来ますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51658/lualatex-luatexja-fontspec-%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%92-%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)において、プロジェクト内からフォントを取得するには、下記の解決が提案されました：

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

残念ながら、これはエラーを起こします：

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 C:\Users
          \i\Documents\TeX\LuaLaTeX_Development
l.6 ...sdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}
                                                  /}
```

色々調べて、不明コントロールシーケンスは`\Users`での`\`だと分かりました。解決するには、下記の解決が[提案されました](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482030/31274)：

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(-2, lfs.currentdir())}/}
```

でも、この解決は正しいパス区切りに差し替える事ではなく、これを削除する事をしています。このように、

```
C:Users/i/Documents/TeX/LuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc
```

は

```
C:UsersiDocumentsTeXLuaLaTeX_Development/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc
```

になります。どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

---

### 再現

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

# 以前解決
# \edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir())}/}

\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir():gsub('\string\\', '/'))}/}

\setmainjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRME.ttc
]{HGS Mincho}

\setsansjfont[
    Path          = \currfileabsdir,
    UprightFont   = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGM.ttc,
    BoldFont      = fonts/HGS_Gothic/HGRGE.ttc,
]{HGS Gothic}


\begin{document}
  日本語 Latin letters Кириллица
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` は置換結果と共にマッチの合計数（ここでは `\` を `/` に置換した個数）も返します．式を括弧で囲んで次のようにすればよいと思います．

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint((lfs.currentdir():gsub('\string\\', '/')))}/}
```

Comment: 多くの苦労の後で動いてくれました。感謝致します！

Answer (score 0):

単純な解決法ですが，Lua でパス中のすべての `\` を `/` に置き換えれば，"Undefined control sequence" エラーを回避して目的のパスが得られると思います．

```
\edef\currfileabsdir{\directlua{tex.sprint(lfs.currentdir():gsub('\string\\', '/'))}/}
```

Comment: @wtsnjb, ご回答、誠にありがとうございます。ほぼ正しい絶対パスを得ましたが、`C:/Users/i/Documents/TeX/LuaLaTeX_Development5/fonts/HGS_Mincho/HGRMB.ttc`に`LuaLaTeX_Development`の後でどういう訳か`5`が追加されました。これを削除すれば、正解になります・・・ 念のために質問の所に再現例を追加致しました。宜しければ、ご覧を為さいませんでしょうか。